how to create 3d plots on any model design like mall, airports, school
I want to make density analysis plots for areas such as schools, shopping malls and airports. The plots I want to draw are heat maps or bar plots on a 3D map, just like the Pydeck library does. I just want to have different structures on the ground and around the relevant areas, such as escalators, planes, classrooms, etc. My ultimate goal is to integrate it with streamlite and examine the density map at varying time intervals. How can i create this kind of 3D environment model and create a heat map on it?
Example plot;
https://docs.wrld3d.com/android/latest/docs/examples/add-a-heatmap-to-an-indoor-map/
I looked at some sites that let you draw 3D models, such as three.js, but I wasn't sure if I was on the right track.
